# Buiding a BackSpace and Enter function in custom Python tkinter program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm building a simulator program on python 3 Tkinter window. The progress is now disrupt due to a bug in the input program I build myself.

The broken code that I'm working on right now:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
prompt = '      Press any key      '
label1 = Label(root, text=prompt, bg='black', fg='green')
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
prompt2=''
def key(event):
    global prompt2
if event.char == event.keysym:
    prompt2 = prompt2 + event.char
elif len(event.char) == 1:
    prompt2 = prompt2 + event.char
else:
    pass
label1.config(text=prompt2)
root.bind_all('<Key>', key)
root.update()
root.mainloop()
```

So, what I want to do (and trying to do) is:

1. Build a function that allow the user to use BackSpace and stop them from using Enter (as I don't want them to move to a new line).
2. Set a variable to True, give the program a signal for when to start (taking input) and when to stop.

But I can't seem to do this. Any suggestions for 1 or 2? Please tell me in the comment section.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you comparing `event.char` to `event.keysym`? That will always be `True` for printable characters, and always be `False` for character sequences and special characters (like <kbd>⇦</kbd> and <kbd>↲</kbd>).

How about this (*untested*)?

```
import string
import tkinter as tk
# See side note 1

def key_event(label, event):
    label_text = label.cget("text")
    if event.keysym == "backspace":
        label.config(text=label_text[:-1])
    elif event.keysym == "return":
        # Disallow 'return'
        pass
    elif event.char in string.ascii_lowercase:
        # Character is an ASCII letter
        label.config(text=label_text + event.char)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    prompt = "      Press any key      "
    label = tk.Label(root, text=prompt, bg="black", fg="green")
    label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    label.bind("<Key>", lambda e: key_event(label, e))
    # See side note 2
    label.focus()
    # Give keyboard focus
    root.mainloop()
```

---

Side note 1: avoid using wildcard imports (`from ... import *`). Instead, alias `tkinter` 'as' `tk`:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
...
```

Side note 2: avoid using global variables, prefer using a class (provided you know how to use them properly, see below section for an example), or for really small pieces of code, share variables using lambdas like I did.

---

```
import string
import tkinter as tk


class EditableLabel(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Key>", self._key_event)

    def _key_event(self, event):
        keysym, char = event.keysym, event.char
        text = self.cget("text")
        if keysym == "backspace":
            self.config(text=text[:-1])
        elif keysym == "return":
            pass
        elif char in string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits:
            self.config(text=text + char)


class MyApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._add_and_draw_widgets()

    def _add_and_draw_widgets(self):
        for i in range(3):
            EditableLabel(self, text="Label #{}".format(i)).grid(column=0, row=i)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MyApplication(root)
    app.grid(column=0, row=0)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: can you do it so the program is run on tkinter canvas please?

Comment: @hungnguyen What do you mean 'put the application on a canvas'? FYI, I'm not a code writing service. If you know enough Python, you can learn more about Tcl / Tkinter [here](http://tkdocs.com), [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/), and [here](https://www.tcl.tk/doc/).

Comment: Fine, btw, event.keysym == "backspace" must be BackSpace and event.keysym == "return" must be Return for it to work, and you forgot to call the main() function, but thanks anyway @Coal_ :)